# additional X" instead of first X and second?

Tags: claim-construction

Why would we say further comprising a second X, as opposed to saying further comprising an additional X? Then what if there can be a second, third, fourth, fifth, etc.?

Comment: "a second X" sounds more precise and numbering it gives you a way to unambiguously refer to it. As your questions get more specific (although somewhat repetitive) I wouldn't expect a lot of energy being put in to answers.

Comment: Yes, I know I seem to ask similar questions over again. However, although I have gained a great deal reading the answers, the answers have not worked for my situation fully. That is my fault for asking questions poorly. Perhaps my situation does not fit the common scenarios, which may be a good or bad thing for an invention I don't know. Alas, I appreciate all I have learned.

Comment: This is a complex and sometimes seeming illogical field. Sometimes actually illogical. Please feel free to keep asking, of course. Speaking for myself, I'm running out of interest.